# Multiple inputs with different data types using scanf()

Tags: c++, c

I am working on some project and I am stuck on one problem.
I am not able to use `scanf()` function properly. I want to scan multiple inputs with different data types.
But I don't know what the problem is. There are no compilation errors.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    unsigned char minx[1024], x, y, z;

    printf("Enter four ints: ");
    scanf( "%s %x %c %i", &minx, &x, &y, &z);

    printf("You wrote: %s %x %c %i", minx, x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: Which compiler your using, curious to know, how on earth the compiler didn’t point out any error?

Comment: Since you tagged with C++ language, you should use `cin` so you don't have to worry about the format specifiers.

Comment: You should tell `scanf` the maximum string size so you don't overflow your array of characters.

Comment: Since you tagged with C++ language, use `std::string` and `std::getline` to read in text.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer not all compilers perform printf/scanf validation at compile time

Answer (score 1):

Your prompt says "Enter four ints", but you haven't declared any variables of type `int`.  You have

```
unsigned char minx[1024], x, y, z;
```

which gives you one array of 1024 unsigned chars, and three individual unsigned chars.

You then wrote

```
scanf( "%s %x %c %i", &minx, &x, &y, &z);
```

You said you didn't get any compiler errors.  If possible, I have to encourage you to get a better compiler!  Mine warned me about all sorts of things on this line:

```
format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'unsigned char (*)[1024]'
format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the argument has type 'unsigned char *'
format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'unsigned char *'
```

If you want to enter a string, a hexadecimal integer, a character, and another integer, make your variable types match:

```
char str[100];
int hex;
char c;
int anotherint;

scanf("%99s %x %c %i", str, &hex, &c, &anotherint);

printf("You wrote: %s %x %c %i\n", str, hex, c, anotherint);
```

I used `%99s` to make sure I didn't overflow `char str[100]`.

Also, notice that you do not need `&` before `str` in the `scanf` call.